# Displaying Row Contents of JQGrid in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am currently using a JQGrid in an ASP MVC4 Razorview page. The structure of my page is

```
<body onload="TimeStamp();">
    <h2>Events as of <div id="timestampDiv"></div></h2>

    <div>
        @Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.EventsGrid, "JQGrid1")
    </div>
</body>
```

What I would like to do is display the individual elements of a record on the page when a row is clicked in the JQGrid. Think of the Windows Event Viewer, where when you click an event, the rest of the form fills with the specific event information. Ideally, the grid and the record information would be on the same page.

My question: I am very new to JQuery and JQGrid. How can I achieve this? Is it possible the way I am thinking about it or is there another, better way to get something similar to what I want?

Thank you.

UPDATE: I have tried:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#JQGrid1").jqGrid({
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    // using id here to get details from server and display them
                    jQuery('#appDiv').text("test");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This causes my grid to disappear from the page.

UPDATE2: It seems to me (tell me if I am wrong) that doing the above code rebuilds a jqgrid (like a constructor) and would need more code to work. Since my JQGrid is already created and passed into the view, I must need to setup the onselectrow event handler in the controller. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You'll have to hook row click event and use it to populate the form.
More specifically, you'll have to hook `onSelectRow` event of jqGrid

For example: your grid has the ID `JQGrid1`

We'll use this ID in JavaScript code to hook `onSelectRow` event like the following:

```
$("#JQGrid1").jqGrid({
   onSelectRow: function(id){ 
      // using id here to get details from server and display them
   }
});
```

**Update:**

Since you have already created the grid using server side wrapper, the above code will try to reinitialize the grid. Try the following code and see if it helps.

```
$('#JQGrid1').jqGrid('setGridParam', 
 { 
    onSelectRow: function(id){ alert(id); } 
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate more on the term "hook"? I get that I need to make the grid communicate with the page, but I have no idea what that would look like. Can you maybe give me some more searchable terms?

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I will give this a whirl and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have updated my question with your code. Please check it over and let me know what i might be doing incorrect. I am not sure how to take what you gave my and make it a working bit of code.

Comment: Did you run this code? is it working? BTW, wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: I have updated the code in my question to reflect the change you recommended. it doesn't work and it causes my jqgrid to fail to load properly. What you are saying makes sense, I am sure I just have a syntactical error somewhere.

Comment: Yep, I actually got it working yesterday using the method you added to your answer. Thanks! I'll mark it as the answer. Another thing to note is that the code you game needs to go after the server side creation of the grid (which happens at document-ready). By putting that code at the bottom of the page, it works great.